# convert image to file and send to volley and json url

Tags: android, file, android-volley, multipart

I am trying to update a profile with an image and other details using Volley.

I have to convert the image file and send it to the url as parameter.

I also have to parse all the other details to update the profile.

How can I update the profile image?

```
               url = "http://192.168.1.30:1021/mobileapi/profile_update.html?&user_id="+user+"&firstname="+First.getText().toString()+
                        "&lastname="+last.getText().toString()+"&secondaryemail="+sEmail.getText().toString()+
                        "&phonemobile="+mob.getText().toString()+"&aboutus="+work.getText().toString()+"&phonework="+phone.getText().toString()+
                        "&skypeid="+skypeid.getText().toString()+"&gender="+gender+"&smtp_password="+mpass.getText().toString()+"&image="+fos;

                url=url.trim().replaceAll("\\s+","");
                System.out.println("url" + url);
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pDialog.show();
                pDialog.dismiss();
                queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

                request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        try {
                            System.out.println("updaa" + response.toString());
                            JSONObject update = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            int httpcode = Integer.parseInt(update.getString("status"));
                            if (httpcode == 200) {
                                String mess = update.getString("message");
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mess, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                int userid = Integer.parseInt(update.getString("user_id"));
                                String fname = update.getString("firstname");
                                String lname = update.getString("lastname");
                                String mail = update.getString("email");
                                String smail=update.getString("secondary_email");
                             /*   String ph= String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(update.getString("phone_work")));
                                String phone= String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(update.getString("phone_mobile")));*/
                                String skype_id = update.getString("skype_id");
                                String user_title = update.getString("user_title");
                                String imgUrl = update.getString("image");

                                editor.putString("name", fname);
                                editor.putString("userid", String.valueOf(userid));
                                editor.putString("lname",lname);
                                editor.putString("mail",mail);
                                editor.putString("skype",skype_id);
                                editor.putString("image",imgUrl);
       //                                    editor.putString("phone",       String.valueOf(ph));
                                editor.putString("work",user_title);
                                editor.putString("smail",smail);
              //                                    editor.putString("phone", String.valueOf(phone));
                                editor.commit();


                            } else {
                                JSONObject typ = response.getJSONObject(0);
                                String message = typ.getString("message");
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override

                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                System.out.println("result" + error.getLocalizedMessage()+"__"+error.getMessage());
                                Log.e("Volley", "Error");

                            }
                        }){
                                                                                  };


                queue.add(request);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}


private void opengallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Show only images, no videos or anything else
    intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {


    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = intent.getData();

        try {
            /*Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
            imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));*/

            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(bitmap));
            Bpro.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            File file = new File(uri + ".png");
            file = new File(extStorageDirectory, uri + ".png");
            Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + uri);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fos);


           /* fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);*/

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

JSON response

```
[{  
    "smtp_password":"abdul",
    "status":"200",
    "user_type":"2",
    "skype_id":"skype",
    "emp_id":"N0418",
    "phone_work":"9864545454",
    "image":"http:\/\/192.168.1.30:1021\/uploads\/Nandha\/profile_image\/180_200\/45571.png",
    "lastname":"Rahman",
    "firstname":"Abdul",
    "user_title":"android",
    "message":"Profile has been updated successfully",
    "email":"4dZR9RLF@gmail.com",
    "gender":"1",
    "user_id":"45571",
    "secondary_email":"abdul@gmail.com",
    "phone_mobile":"9892545454"
}]
```

Comment: What is the problem? Show your JSON response also.

Comment: urlhttp://192.168.1.30:1021/mobileapi/profile_update.html?&user_id=45571&firstname=Abdul&lastname=Rahman&secondaryemail=abdul@gmail.com&phonemobile=9892545454&aboutus=android&phonework=9864545454&skypeid=skype&gender=1&smtp_password=abdul&image=null i have got image as null even if the image select from gallery

Comment: i have to update profile image also how i send the image as file

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using a `Uri.Builder` for that url string instead of all that string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

use this code ..it works for me .Its sends multipart images.

```
 private void saveProfileDetails() {
    // loading or check internet connection or something...
    // ... then
    String url = "http://51.76.27.90:8080/post/new/";
    VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            System.out.println("statuscode is " + response.statusCode);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            String errorMessage = "Unknown error";
            if (networkResponse == null) {
                if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                    errorMessage = "Request timeout";
                } else if (error.getClass().equals(NoConnectionError.class)) {
                    errorMessage = "Failed to connect server";
                }
            } else {
                String result = new String(networkResponse.data);
                try {
                    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
                    String status = response.getString("status");
                    String message = response.getString("message");

                    Log.e("Error Status", status);
                    Log.e("Error Message", message);

                    if (networkResponse.statusCode == 404) {
                        errorMessage = "Resource not found";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {
                        errorMessage = message + " Please login again";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
                        errorMessage = message + " Check your inputs";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 500) {
                        errorMessage = message + " Something is getting wrong";
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.i("Error", errorMessage);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", "a@a.com");
            params.put("category", "product");
            params.put("type", "product");
            params.put("title", "i am done ");
            params.put("content", "contentssssssssssssssssssssssss");
            params.put("location", "Bangalore");

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
            // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
            params.put("imageC", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", AppClass.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), colorImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));
            params.put("imageBW", new DataPart("file_cover.jpg", AppClass.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), blackAndWhiteImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));

            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
}
```

and this is your VollySingleton function

```
 /**
 * Created by snehasish on 29/7/16.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
* Singleton volley to populate request into single queue.


*/
public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;

/**
 * Private constructor, only initialization from getInstance.
 *
 * @param context parent context
 */
private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruBitmapCache(mCtx);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Singleton construct design pattern.
 *
 * @param context parent context
 * @return single instance of VolleySingleton
 */
public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
 }



/**
 * Get current request queue.
 *
 * @return RequestQueue
 */
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

/**
 * Add new request depend on type like string, json object, json array request.
 *
 * @param req new request
 * @param <T> request type
 */
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

/**
 * Get image loader.
 *
 * @return ImageLoader
 */
public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
}
```

if it helps pls make this answer as right!

Comment: dont forget to make it as right..obviously if it is helpful for you.:)

Comment: i want to pass the path to the url i have mentioned

Comment: To do that first you have to store that image in a imageview ....and  call that Imageview like i did here   params.put("imageC", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", AppClass.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), colorImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));  here colorImage is a imageView....

Comment: lrubitmapcahe class required